# Navigate Soft Keyboard with Remote Control

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm looking for a solution for navigating the android soft keyboard with a remote control like this one:

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Generic-remote-control-shallow-focus.jpg
```

The issue that I have now is that when I select a text box with the remote control the soft keyboard comes up but there is no way to select the characters on the soft keyboard using the remote.

The remote control has only:

```
all numbers 0-9
cursor keys arrow up, down, left, right
ok/enter button
```

I would like to navigate to the character I want to enter with the cursor keys and add it to the text area by pressing the ok/enter button.

Thanks

Comment: ever find a solution?